# How to add a simple transition using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

Sorry if i'm being a noob, i'm not that experienced with jquery (yet). I've been reading books but I can't figure out how to add a transition to this...

```
<script>
$(function(ready){
$('select[id="options-1"]').change(function(){  

if ($(this).val() == "1")
     $('.preview-1').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

if ($(this).val() == "2")
     $('.preview-2').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

if ($(this).val() == "3")
     $('.preview-3').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

if ($(this).val() == "4")
     $('.preview-4').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

if ($(this).val() == "5")
     $('.preview-5').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

});
});
</script>
```

This script gets the value from a drop down menu and uses it to change the class on an image (wrapped in an LI tag), which makes it visible:

```
<li id="preview-5869" class="preview-2">
<li id="preview-2388" class="preview-1 active">
```

The class 'active' makes the image visible. In the above two lines of code, the li tag with the class 'preview-1 active' will be visible.

What I am trying to do is make a transition that instead of changing the pictures instantly, there would be a nice fade effect. Could you guys please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Comment: Not directly related, but you can clean up your code: `$('.preview-' +  this.value).addClass("active")`.  And use an id selector instead of an attribute selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` function. This is my example for how I created that effect. Remember that you cannot slow down the process of removing a class name or adding a new one. So you need to first `fadeOut` all the elements that are visible at present and then `fadeIn` the one that has been selected. Here is my example for how I achieved this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sarcastyx/Xhu4x/